# How to install an msi created by Visual Studio 2010 to a different app pool than default?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a web application created in Visual Studio 2010 built with .Net Framework 4.0.

The deployment project creates the msi but the problem is I have got two app pools on my web server (Windows Server 2003) - one (defaultAppPool) that works with .Net Framework 3.5 and another (myAppPool) that works with .Net Framework 4.0.

I want my msi to auto deploy in myAppPool application pool. Is there a way to do it?

I already checked the solution that is given here  ([Changing the application pool through a Web Deployment Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167232/changing-the-application-pool-through-a-web-deployment-project)) but unfortunately it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

D

Comment: No answer for two days - it seems like no one has ever tried this? Guys I am short of time, please anyone can suggest a solution? If any other info is needed, please let me know.